# File with JPG extension acts like a GIF with a cat shooting a gun with heavy kickback

Tags: image, gif, jpeg, file-extension

I recently came across this image which seems like a normal GIF:

[image: seems a gif image]

Even [imgur](http://imgur.com/) stores it as a GIF when I uploaded it here.

But when I saw the link, it was a JPEG image, unlike a GIF than what I had expected!

Here's the link: https://fbcdn-sphotos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/559307_325955130827518_630404691_n.jpg

Comment: It's a GIF with the wrong extension. The first 6 bytes of the image are GIF89a, which is the [magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Interchange_Format) for a GIF file.

Comment: And a new meme is born.

Comment: Is this seriously off topic??

Comment: I liked your title. Haters gonna hate.

Comment: What makes it on topic other than filling in the question box?

Comment: Finally, a canonical question on this topic with a title I can actually *remember.*

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is actually a .gif - look at the headers of the HTTP response.

The [MIME type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) is image/gif

So it doesn't matter what the URL says at the end - it's the MIME type that determines how your browser interprets it.

A lot of sites use this (I guess to throw off harvesters?) imgur.com often reports the wrong extension, for example. Try going to `i.imgur.com/yourpic.txt` - it should still show up as a proper gif.

Comment: Hmm... If you're using chrome, hit f12. Then go to the "Network" tab and look for your image. Click on it, and check out the "headers" tab that appears. Not sure for other browsers, sorry.

Comment: @gopi1410 use the chrome dev tools if you have chrome. Ctrl Shift I should bring it up. Refresh the page to catch types

Comment: C-S-i also works for Opera (Dragonfly)