# Is this a web page or an image?

Tags: html, image, encoding

http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/squirrel/

According to the author,

> This is an embedded landing page for an image. You can link to this
>   URL and get the HTML document you are viewing right now (soon to
>   include essential squirrel facts); or embed the exact same URL as an
>   image on your own squirrel-themed page: `<a
>   href="http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/squirrel/">Click here!</a> <img
>   src="http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/squirrel/">` No server-side hacks
>   involved - the magic happens in your browser.

In other words, if you pop that URL into your browser it renders as a web page, but you can also use the same URL as an image source.

What kind of witchcraft is at work here?

<sub>(Edit: [source code](http://pastebin.com/jMqbie7C) from the above link if that site ever goes offline.)</sub>

Comment: The answer to your *title* would be: both, apparently.

Comment: This is the only time I've see `img src="#"` used. :P

Comment: It is a encoded image

Comment: I know this is old, but could this technique be used as a XSS attack?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The file you linked is a polyglot - a combination of languages. It can be read and understood as **both** an image and an HTML file. It's a simple trick. If you look at the HTML source you can see this at the top:

```
ÿØÿà
```

A quick Google shows this looks like a JPEG header. What the creator does is store the HTML in JPEG metadata, and the JPEG image data in a html comment. Pretty nifty but not magic.

To hide the JPEG header he uses CSS rules to hide the body and show only some elements:

```
body { visibility: hidden; }
.n { visibility: visible; position: absolute; ...... }
```

Also note that it isn't valid HTML, for example because the comment to hide the image data is not closed, but that browsers still happily accept and render it.

Comment: I wonder if it would be possible to create a valid JPEG file that ends with `-->`

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Not paying 122 CHF to find it out, sorry. http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=25431

Comment: This may be unrelated to this, but it made me think of it and it seems at least somewhat fitting: Would it be possible to make this html file (gupi1410 pointed out the file is called index.html) have a php redirect in it? So, when used in `img src='imgLink'` it displays an image and when user goes to `imgLink` they're redirected to a "haha, can't direct link my images" page?

Comment: @DouglasA.Crosby: Yes, that would be possible (though it would not be a PHP redirect, but a HTML + Javascript one), but probably not useful. Generally you __want__ linking and __don't want__ embedding.

Comment: Generally not, I agree. Im was thinking for a photography portfolio type website (Flikr, perhaps) where they want links to flikr.com/user/photo instead of photos.flikr.com/12345/etc/dir/file.jpg (for example).

Comment: @DouglasA.Crosby: such annoying practices are usually done server side.

Answer (score 4):

Its a html page with html content along with image data.

Check out the header, it contains jpg header. In the source the first line contains `ÿØÿà` which is a jpeg header.
The url http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/squirrel/index.html (appended index.html), clearly shows its an html file. So apparently  this may be called **both** as a web page or an image!

You can easily rename a jpg file (or any image file) as .html & when you open in your browser, it would just show an image, just like any other image.

A recent similar trick I remember is that renaming gif to jpg as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529941/file-with-jpg-extension-acts-like-a-gif-with-a-cat-shooting-a-gun-with-heavy-kic), but still the data is gif & the headers contain gif.