# Showing the logo with the JS library

Tags: javascript, image

I want to *copyright* my JS library, or more "showing that it's ME who did it", like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11587119/1344937).

The expected result would be that if you write

```
<script src="myLib.js" ></script>
```

It's a completely working library.

And if you write

```
<img src="myLib.js" />
```

It will show my logo.

I would like an explanation of the way to do it step by step.

P.S: The answers of [Is this a web page or an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11587119/1344937) are explaining how it can work; but what I want is to know the procedure to do for any image with any file.

Comment: Don't do this, as it will make the js file a lot bigger than needed. I've never tried embedding a JS file as an image, so it's not as if people will realise this works anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible with javascript because with this trick your file has to start with `0xFF 0xD8 0xFF 0xE0...` and there is no way to make javascript ignore that. It will just immediately give up because of a syntax error.

Any other binary format likely has the same problem as well. They'd need to start with `0x2F 0x2A` (`/*`) to even consider it.

It's different with html because html is not afraid of seeing `0xFF 0xD8 0xFF 0xE0...`

Comment: Then, can you tell me how I do it with HTML?

Comment: @Mageek I'm not too good with photoshop, but you should be able to insert a comment to your jpeg file. That comment should be your html. The html has to end with `<!--`. Nothing more to it really.

Comment: Is there a way to make it valid? (Comment that end with `-->`)

Comment: @Mageek nope because the JPEG comment ends at `<!--`, after that it's JPEG binary data which must be in certain format. You can only mess with the JPEG comment.

Comment: Thanks :) I found : http://www.thinkfu.com/blog/gifjavascript-polyglots And they say it's a javascript-gif polyglot. How? (You said it's not possible)

Comment: @Mageek I didn't say it's not possible altogether (just with JPEG). the GIF file starts with a valid javascript string assignment. `GIF89a=` is valid start of a javascript file.