# div centered but also fixed

Tags: html, css

I know its possible a web game (travian) does it. what I'm trying to do is have a div of say 800 width that does 2 things:

First: if browser is more than 800 pixels wide the dive centers itself in the browser (this I have figured out)

Second if I drag my browser window smaller, my div scrolls off the left side of the page. I want it not go past the left side ( 0px) of page when page is smaller than 800.

Travian does it but I can't figure it out so any help would be appreciated.

this centers my box but when resizing browser it cuts off the left side (lets it pan past left edge of browser)

```
#NavBar {
    position: absolute;
    width: 425px;
    margin:0 -225px 0 -225px;
    height: 70px;
    z-index: 4;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 425px;
    top: 15px;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: show your code please

Comment: Please post some relevant HTML/CSS demonstrating what you have tried.

Comment: Your writing and your code do not fit together. What you would like to achieve can easily be done by the use of **media queries**. And having a _**felxible**_ container in combination with _**fixed**_ pixel values cannot work together. And when using media queries use relative units like `em`, because you design for the real viewport size and not one in pixels.

Comment: first I'm using media queries for a lot of stuff and second I just wanted a simple div that if the browser area was bigger than the div it would center itself. the whole positioning thing I'm still wrapping my head around

Comment: SERIOUSLY? off topic ? how is a programming question on a programming related site Off Topic ?

Allow me to refer j08691 to his own question that if mine is off topic so is his:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11587119/is-this-a-web-page-or-an-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this CSS

```
.div-class{
 width: 800px;
height:400px;
margin:0 auto;

}
```

Comment: had to modify this a tiny bit (add position:relative or the div hid under the rest but this worked for me thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Preview:** http://jsfiddle.net/PJC4a/1/embedded/result/ (**try resizing window**)

**Code:** http://jsfiddle.net/PJC4a/1/

```
.box {
    width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: blue;
    margin: auto;
}
```

This is one of the tricks that can be used to center div horizontally using css only.